# Is there a word for an irrational feeling of wellbeing?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for an irrational feeling of wellbeing, for example, as may be experienced as a result of antidepressant medication?

Comment: You mean being "***high***" on antidepressants?

Comment: How about *optimism*? Surely that's irrational these days ...

Answer (score 1):

The word is ***euphoria***.

The OED entry follows:

> Pathol. ‘A word used to express well-being, or the perfect ease and
>   comfort of healthy persons, especially when the sensation occurs in a
>   sick person’ ( New Sydenham Soc. Lexicon). Now frequently in
>   non-technical contexts: a state of cheerfulness or well-being, esp.
>   one based on over-confidence or over-optimism.
>
> 1727–51   E. Chambers Cycl.
>
> 1882   W. James Let. 2 Nov. (1920) I. 211   Having taken the plunge,
>   the cutaneous glow and ‘euphoria’ (vide dictionary) succeeded.
>
> 1922   R. S. Woodworth Psychol. vii. 120   The warmed-up person feels
>   ready for business, full of ‘ginger’ or ‘pep’—in short, full of life.
>   The name ‘euphoria’, which means about the same as ‘feeling good’, is
>   given to this condition.
>
> 1927   F. B. Young Portrait of Clare 607   In this detached euphoria
>   she began to approve of Dr. Boyd.
>
> 1939   A. Huxley After Many a Summer i. iii. 37   The delightful
>   condition of euphoria into which those poor kids and Clancy's good
>   news had plunged him.
>
> 1954   X. Fielding Hide & Seek 215   In this abnormal silence, which
>   only intensified our state of euphoria, we settled down to sleep.
>
> 1960   W. H. Auden Homage to Clio 89   Good Queen Victoria, In a fit
>   of euphoria, Commanded Disraeli To blow up the Old Bailey.
>
> 1964   Ann. Reg. 1963 9   But this euphoria was not to last.
>
> 1971   Physics Bull. Apr. 216/1   In the post war euphory, it was easy
>   to obtain support for fundamental research.

Answer (score 0):

[Sedate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sedate?s=t) (adj) has a strong medical connotation. Also [complacent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/complacent?s=t) carries a sense of wellbeing or satisfaction (often in spite of surrounding danger).